# DataTable Charts issue in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, date, chart

I am working on drawing a chart using datatable. So I followed the instructions in https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/charts_datatable
I noticed a 30 days shift between the data and the chart xValue. For example in the following code, the date of the first image is 2010_01_01 although in the chart is 31-01-2010.
I wonder if anyone could help me solve this problem?

```
    // Import the example feature collection and subset the forest feature.
var forest = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/google/charts_feature_example')
                 .filter(ee.Filter.eq('label', 'Forest'));

// Load MODIS vegetation indices data and subset a decade of images.
var vegIndices = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13A1')
                     .filter(ee.Filter.date('2010-01-01', '2020-01-01'))
                     .select(['NDVI', 'EVI']);

// Define a function to format an image timestamp as a JavaScript Date string.
function formatDate(img) {
  var date = ee.String(img.date().format('YYYY, MM, dd'));
  return ee.String('Date(').cat(date).cat(ee.String(')'));
}

// Build a feature collection where each feature has a property that represents
// a DataFrame row.
var reductionTable = vegIndices.map(function(img) {
  // Reduce the image to the mean of pixels intersecting the forest ecoregion.
  var stat = img.reduceRegion(
      {reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry: forest, scale: 500});

  // Extract the reduction results along with the image date.
  var date = formatDate(img);   // x-axis values.
  var evi = stat.get('EVI');    // y-axis series 1 values.
  var ndvi = stat.get('NDVI');  // y-axis series 2 values.

  // Make a list of observation attributes to define a row in the DataTable.
  var row = ee.List([date, evi, ndvi]);

  // Return the row as a property of an ee.Feature.
  return ee.Feature(null, {'row': row});
});

// Aggregate the 'row' property from all features in the new feature collection
// to make a server-side 2-D list (DataTable).
var dataTableServer = reductionTable.aggregate_array('row');

// Define column names and properties for the DataTable. The order should
// correspond to the order in the construction of the 'row' property above.
var columnHeader = ee.List([[
  {label: 'Date', role: 'domain', type: 'date'},
  {label: 'EVI', role: 'data', type: 'number'},
  {label: 'NDVI', role: 'data', type: 'number'}
]]);

// Concatenate the column header to the table.
dataTableServer = columnHeader.cat(dataTableServer);

// Use 'evaluate' to transfer the server-side table to the client, define the
// chart and print it to the console.
dataTableServer.evaluate(function(dataTableClient) {
  var chart = ui.Chart(dataTableClient).setChartType('LineChart').setOptions({
    title: 'Annual NDVI Time Series with Inter-Annual Variance',
    intervals: {style: 'area'},
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Day of year',
      titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true},
    },
    vAxis: {title: 'NDVI (x1e4)', titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}},
    lineWidth: 5,
    colors: ['e37d05', '1d6b99'],
    curveType: 'function'
  });
  print(chart);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the discrepancy, good catch!
I've updated the example in the EE Guide to account for JS date expecting zero-based month. It should be live in a day or two.

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked much with these charts, but I can give an educated guess on your problems.

The 1 month offset: The charting library [docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam) says it's using `zero-based month` - January is month 0. In Earth Engine on the other hand, January is month 1. You have to subtract 1 from the month before passing it to the charting library.

Then you have what I suppose is a time-zone mix-up. I'm not sure how to cleanly fix that. Here's the general idea of the issue:

```
var date = ee.Date('2000-01-01', 'Europe/Rome')
date.get('year').format() // Prints 1999, not 2000
```

It doesn't seem to depend on the client (browser) location (I tried with a VPN). Hard-coding a 1h difference did the trick for me at least. Here's the best I can do:

```
function formatDate(img) {
  var year = img.date().get('year').format()
  var month = img.date().get('month').subtract(1).format()
  var day = img.date().get('day').format()
  return ee.String('Date(')
    .cat(year)
    .cat(', ')
    .cat(month)
    .cat(', ')
    .cat(day)
    .cat(ee.String(', 1)'));
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/863b2a18e7cf1a066d5e5dff794da712

Comment: Thanks for debugging this, Daniel!
I've updated the example in the EE Guide to account for JS date expecting zero-based month. It should be live in a day or two.

Comment: Daniel Wiell; thank you very much for your help. It worked for me but needed to add one day to match the chart with the image's date.                                                          var day = img.date().get('day').add(1).format()

Comment: Note that the date constructor also accepts the Unix timestamp:

`return ee.String('Date(').cat(img.date().millis().format()).cat(')')`